# Overlaying geom_bar and missing values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, overlay, geom-bar

I want to overlay 3 geom_bar to make clear an evolution over 3 years.
My data is as follows for each year:

Example : PerfDist2021 (my dataframe for 2021)

| Districts | Perf |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 60 |

On my Yaxis I have the performance (in %) and on the Xaxis I have the number corresponding to the district (from 1 to 25 and there is also a 31th).

I made this :

```
ggplot(data=NULL, aes(Districts, Perf)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = "2019"), data = PerfDist2019, stat="identity" ,alpha = 0.5, col="red") +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = "2020" ), data = PerfDist2020, stat="identity", alpha = 0.5, col="green") +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = "2021" ), data = PerfDist2021, stat="identity", alpha = 0.5, col="blue")
```

- But first, I can't see all my districts, I don't know how to get them
  all visible it's like R erase some or is just not precise with my
  Xaxis (see picture in link).
- Secondly, I don't know how to change the color of the geom_bar, I can
  just change the color of the frame of the bar with col=... , and the
  data is not very readable this way.
- Third, the colours blend together, it is sometimes hard to
  distinguish the three. I tried with several combination of colors, it
  is always the same. Is there a way to avoir this issue of mixing
  colors ? Thanks you

[image: What I did]

Thanks you for your help !

PS : You can ask for any precision !

Comment: Maybe you can change the type of Districts to factor, e.g. PerfDist2019$Districts <- factor(PerfDist2019$Districts, levels = 1:31).

Comment: Hello Léo! In SO, if a new question has appeared on top of an old one, you either: (i) edit your original question and add the new one at the bottom; or (ii) post a completely new question. You don't post it as an answer because it is not one.  I've edited your question for you.

Comment: Oh sorry for that, I'm a beginner in stack as well :D .

Answer (score 0):

`fill` is the aesthetic that controls the color of the bars. `color` controls colors of lines, in this case, the frames, as you noted. So you want to delete the `col =` arguments and add `scale_fill_manual` to associate which color each custom `fill` name should have.

Also, the three repeated `geom_bar` isn't too good, if you had 12 years you wouldn't want to have 12 `geom_bar`. To change that, you can `rbind` your three datasets, and add a column specifying from which year it comes from, and than saying to ggplot to fill the bars following that column.

Lastly, as @h45 said, you can change the type of Districts to factor to avoid the missing levels.

```
PerfDist = rbind(
  cbind(PerfDist2019, Year = "2019"),
  cbind(PerfDist2019, Year = "2020"),
  cbind(PerfDist2019, Year = "2021"))

PerfDist$Districts <- factor(PerfDist$Districts, levels = 1:31)
  
ggplot(PerfDist, aes(Districts, Perf, fill = Year)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "identity", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

Thats it for the answer, now just a note for you to improve your next answers, please read [how to make a great r reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Breproducible-example).

Comment: Okay thanks you I will try and I come back !

Comment: Thanks you for your help, I tried your code, it works but it don't produce an overlaying, for each district it plot bars on an additive way. Do you see what I mean ? I really want to make an overlay for each district of the 3 years.

Comment: Oh i see. That happened because `geom_bar` by default has the `position` argument set to `"stack"` (which is a shorthand for `position_stack()`). If you change it to `position = "identity"` you get your original graph back. As for the mixing colors, that is a side effect of the transparency of the bars. I guess you want the bars to be in a different order for each x-axis tick, which is unusual for ggplot. I opened a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74296730/barplot-with-different-factor-order-for-each-x-axis-tick) about how to do it, you should follow it @Léo

Comment: Thanks you a lot, I found exactly what I searched in the first plot of Ric Villalba, I cannot comment the other question, but thanks you all !